# Angular get viewContainerRef of dynamicly created component

Tags: angular, dynamic, components

in a component I do use a service to load JSON Data. Depending on this data with a tree structure, I want to create new components dynamicly:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { MenuComponent } from '../menu/menu.component';
import { RowComponent } from '../row/row.component';

import { DynamicComponentInterface } from '../../interfaces/dynamicComponentInterface';
import { SlotDirective } from './slot.directive';

import { ContentService } from '../../services/content.service';
import { DynamicComponentsHostService } from '../../services/dynamicComponentsHost.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-slot',
  templateUrl: './slot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slot.component.css']
})
export class SlotComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy  {
  @Input() id:number;
  @ViewChild(SlotDirective) slot: SlotDirective;
  private slotDataTree;
  private componentRef;
  private contentReadySubscription;

  constructor(
    private contentService : ContentService,
    private componentFactoryResolver : ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private dynamicComponentsHostService: DynamicComponentsHostService

  ) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    // get JSON data with TreeStructure from Service
    if(this.contentService.stateReady){
      this.slotDataTree = this.contentService.getCurrentBySlotId(this.id);
      this.renderContentTree();
    }
    else{
      this.contentReadySubscription = this.contentService.getCurrentPageContentReadyObserver().subscribe(stateReady => {
    if(stateReady ){
      this.slotDataTree = this.contentService.getCurrentBySlotId(this.id);
      this.renderContentTree();
    }
      });
    }
  }

  renderContentTree(){
    if(this.slotDataTree){


      let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.dynamicComponentsHostService.getDynamicComponentType(this.slotDataTree.type));
      let viewContainerRef = this.slot.viewContainerRef;
      let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);


      (<DynamicComponentInterface>componentRef.instance).data = this.slotDataTree;

    // Works like a charm.
    // now I want to create children for the newly created component
    // so I need the viewContainerRef of componentRef



    // this delivers a viewRef
      console.log(componentRef.hostView);

    // this delivers sometimes a viewContainerRef in console, but a comile error that _viewRef does not exists

      console.log(componentRef._viewRef._viewContainerRef);

    // I cannot do this in the dynamicly rendered components class its self, because of circular dependencies that would occour then
      /*
      if(this.slotDataTree.children.length){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.slotDataTree.children.length; i++){

      let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.dynamicComponentsHostService.getDynamicComponentType(this.slotDataTree.children[i].type));
      let viewContainerRef = componentRef._viewRef._viewContainerRef;
      let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    }
      }
      */
      if(this.contentReadySubscription){
    this.contentReadySubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.contentReadySubscription){
      this.contentReadySubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

I can create components dynamicly. But I what to create child components to the created component, too. Means I need a viewRefContainer of that component I just created.

I cannot create dynamicly components in the components class that was used to  by created dynamicly because of circular dependencies.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Did u ever get this issue resolved? I have the same need at the moment

Comment: Yes, now I use a Service, thats hosts all Component types that possibly have to been created. Then I use a root component, that creates the first dynamic component. This root component subscribes an observer of the dynamicly created component. The observerble of the dynamicly created component sends its viewRefContainer back to the root component. The root components uses the viewRefContainer to create childComponents an so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got it working :)

Answer (score 2):

Thats how I solved it now. First I use a root component wich is the origin of the dynamic created component tree. Mayby a service would be better:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit, ComponentFactoryResolver, Input, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuComponent } from '../menu/menu.component';
import { DynamicComponent } from '../dynamic/dynamic.component';
import { SlotDirective } from '../../directives/slot.directive';
import { ContentService } from '../../services/content.service';
import { EditService } from '../../services/edit.service';
import { DynamicComponentsHostService } from '../../services/dynamicComponentsHost.service';
import { DynamicComponentsData } from '../../classes/dynamicComponentsData';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slot',
  templateUrl: './slot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slot.component.css']
})
export class SlotComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit  {
  @Input() id:number;
  @ViewChild(SlotDirective) slot: SlotDirective;
  private componentRef;
  private contentReadySubscription;
  public slotDataTree : DynamicComponentsData = new DynamicComponentsData({},false);

  constructor(
    protected contentService : ContentService,
    private editService : EditService,
    private componentFactoryResolver : ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private dynamicComponentsHostService: DynamicComponentsHostService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    var slotData;
    if(this.contentService.stateReady){
      if( slotData = this.contentService.getCurrentBySlotId(this.id) ){
        this.slotDataTree = slotData;
      }
      else{
        this.slotDataTree.type = 'none';
      }
      this.renderContentTree();
    }

    this.contentReadySubscription = this.contentService.getCurrentPageContentReadyObserver().subscribe(stateReady => {
      if(stateReady ){
        if( slotData = this.contentService.getCurrentBySlotId(this.id) ){
          this.slotDataTree = slotData;
        }
        else{
          this.slotDataTree.type = slotData;
        }
        this.renderContentTree();
      }
    });

    DynamicComponentsData.changed.subscribe( changeObject =>{
      this.renderContentTree();
    });
  }

  renderChilds(viewContainerRef,childs){
    for(var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++){
      // create the dynamic component. Use a service to get the types
      let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.dynamicComponentsHostService.getDynamicComponentType(childs[i].type).class);
      let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
      // give some data
      (<DynamicComponent>componentRef.instance).data = childs[i];
      // subscribe an event emitter
      (<DynamicComponent>componentRef.instance).sendViewContainerRef.subscribe(
        (event:any)=>{
          if(event.childs){
            this.renderChilds(event.viewContainerRef, event.childs);
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }

  renderContentTree(){
    let viewContainerRef = this.slot.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    if(this.contentService.getCurrentBySlotId(this.id)){
      this.renderChilds(this.slot.viewContainerRef, this.contentService.getCurrentBySlotId(this.id).children);
      if(this.contentReadySubscription){
        this.contentReadySubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.contentReadySubscription){
      this.contentReadySubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```